# How to read excel using pandas row by row?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, python-requests

So i'm trying to make a program reads a excel sheet and passes the commands into the curl command. So it should read the excel file and pass each variable into the curl command and keep doing it to each row. So I got the curl command to work.

However, when I tried to read my excel sheet. I'm getting this error and not really sure how to fix this so it goes away. 
charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 114: character maps to

So here is my code:

```
import requests
import json
import pprint
import urllib
import sys
import pandas as pd

turl='*'
headers={'authorization':'Basic *'}
data={
         'grant_type':'*',
         'username':'*',
         'password':'*'
          }
token=requests.post(turl,data=data,headers=headers)
jtoken=token.json()
json_str=json.dumps(jtoken)
resp=json.loads(json_str)
jkk=resp['access_token']
print(jkk)

path='C:\\Users\\temp\\Desktop\\Test123.xlsx'
data = []
with open(path) as f:
    for line in f:
        data.append(line.strip().split(','))

data = data[1:]  # get the data without the first row which is data headers
print(data)

for entry in data:  
    name, path, Tname, formatG = entry

    url1='*'
    data={"name": "{}".format(name),
        "path": "{}".format(path) ,
        "Tname" : "{}".format(Tname),
         "formatG":"{}".format(formatG)
         }
    pprint.pprint(response.json())
data_json = json.dumps(data)
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json','Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(jkk)}
response = requests.post(url1, data=data_json, headers=headers)
pprint.pprint(response.json())
```

In my code I have * for privacy reasons. I'm currently having problems reading the excel sheet row by row and passing the data into the curl command.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using `pd.read_excel`?

Comment: I heard is a efficient way to read an excel file. That's the only reason I'm using it.